# Pinia state is not reactive in v-if directive. Am I missing something?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Vue component

```
<template>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header id="header" class="bg-gray-700">
    <nav class="container mx-auto flex justify-start items-center py-5 px-4">
      <!-- App Name -->
      <router-link
        class="text-white font-bold uppercase text-2xl mr-4"
        :to="{ name: 'home' }"
        exact-active-class="no-active"
        >Music</router-link
      >
      <div class="flex flex-grow items-center">
        <!-- Primary Navigation -->
        <ul class="flex flex-row mt-1">
          <!-- Navigation Links -->
          <li>
            <RouterLink class="px-2 text-white" :to="{ name: 'about' }">About</RouterLink>
          </li>
          <li v-if="!userStore.isUserLoggedIn">
            <a class="px-2 text-white" href="#" @click.prevent="toggleAuthModal">
              Login / Register
            </a>
          </li>
          <template v-else>
            <li>
              <RouterLink class="px-2 text-white" :to="{ name: 'manage' }">Manage</RouterLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="px-2 text-white" href="#" @click.prevent="logOut">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
import { mapStores } from 'pinia'
import useModalStore from '@/stores/modal'
import useUserStore from '@/stores/user'

export default {
  name: 'AppHeader',
  computed: {
    ...mapStores(useModalStore, useUserStore)
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAuthModal() {
      this.modalStore.isOpen = !this.modalStore.isOpen
    },
    logOut() {
      this.userStore.signOut()
      if (this.$route.name === 'manage') {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
      }
      console.log(this.userStore.isUserLoggedIn)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Pinia store file

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut
} from 'firebase/auth'
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { firebaseDb } from '@/includes/firebase'

export default defineStore('user', {
  state: () => {
    isUserLoggedIn: false
  },
  actions: {
    async createUser(values) {
      const userCred = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        getAuth(),
        values.email,
        values.password
      )
      await setDoc(doc(firebaseDb, 'users', userCred.user.uid), {
        name: values.name,
        email: values.email,
        age: values.age,
        country: values.country
      })
      await updateProfile(userCred.user, { displayName: values.name })
      this.isUserLoggedIn = true
    },
    async signInUser(values) {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), values.email, values.password)
      this.isUserLoggedIn = true
    },
    signOut() {
      signOut(getAuth())
      this.isUserLoggedIn = false
    }
  }
})
```

When I when click on logout the user has been signed out. Pinia store state is updated with isUserLoggedin value but v-if directive is not evaluated when isUserLoggedIn value changes.

I want to swap the menu lists when user sign out. I expected v-if directive to be reactive.

Comment: As long as isUserLoggedIn is changed, I see no reasons for it to behave like that. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I am missing parentheses in the arrow function that returning the state object.

```
state: () => ({
    isUserLoggedIn: false
  }),
```

Thanks for the effort.